# Login form when using keyсloak

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

Good afternoon everyone. For authorization, my application uses SSO and Keycloak. Is it possible to somehow make it so that you can log in through the authorization form I made, and not through the default keyloak form?

Stack used - ReactJs and Keycloak/web

Comment: Have you read the theming documentation ? https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis Yeah, I know. But this does not suit me, since it is necessary to implement the login form on the front without using the standard ones.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you will lost SSO functionality and you will sacrificy security. So that's really not a good solution.